# IWebProxy equivalent in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

in C# I can do

```
public static IWebProxy GetWebProxy() {
    var proxyUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxyUrl)) {
        var proxy = new WebProxy {
            Address = new Uri(proxyUrl),
            BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        };

        return proxy;
    }

    return null;

}
```

and then create a client like :

```
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = proxy, };
         
        var client  new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true);
```

how to achieve the same using Angular and typescript
for example, using `request` I tried

```
    const options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: endPoint,
proxy: 'xxxxx'
                    headers: {
                        contentHeader,
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                         
                        classId: class_id, 
                        roomId: room_id,
                    }),
                };

                 
                request(options, function (_error: Error, _response: any, data: string) {
}
```

but it didn't work

Comment: is this just for development purposes?

Answer (score 0):

if you're just trying to create a proxy for dev purposes, you can create a file called `proxy.conf.json` in your application root that will look something like:

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000",
      "secure": false
    },
}
```

this will redirect any requests to `localhost:4200` (assuming running on standard port) that starts with `/api` to `localhost:3000/api`

to use it, you set it in your options in `angular.json` in your serve options:

```
"proxyConfig": "./proxy.conf.json"
```

more about this here: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: I need it for cucumber environment,  don't have serve

Comment: if it's for testing then add it to your test configuration options. should still work.